# Batch Apex save error in Eclipse Neon with Force.com IDE

Tags: apex, batch, eclipse, force.com-ide

I am trying to demonstrate batch apex in Eclipse Neon with Force.com IDE. Following is the code -

```
global class BatchApexDemoClass1 implements Database.Batchable<Sobject> {
 global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([Select LeadSource From Lead]);
 }

 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> scope) {
    for (Lead Leads : scope) {
        Leads.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
    }
    update scope;
 }    

 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) { 
    System.debug('Batch apex execution complete.');
 }    }
```

However, when I save the code, I get the following errors-

- Save error: Class BatchApexDemoClass1 must implement the method: void 
   Database.Batchable.finish(Database.BatchableContext)
- Save error: Class BatchApexDemoClass1 must implement the method: void 
   Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List)
- Offline Mode. File only saved locally, not to server
- Save error: Class BatchApexDemoClass1 must implement the method: System.Iterable 
   Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)

I don't know what am I missing in the code. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Your code saves correctly when creating via Setup > Apex Class.  But the Offline Mode is an issue within Eclipse.  A quick Google search turns up this [developer guide page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_work_offline.htm)

> By default, the Force.com IDE creates projects in offline mode. When
>   you work in offline mode, you avoid compiling your org’s Apex code
>   each time you save your files. If, however, you have a stable Internet
>   connection and a small- to medium-sized code base, consider toggling
>   your projects to online mode.
>
> Toggle Between Offline and Online Modes Right-click your project in
>   the Package Explorer and choose Force.com, and then select the mode in
>   which you want to work.

Comment: I have already tried it. But it doesn't change anything. Also your answer would solve error - Offline Mode. File only saved locally, not to server. What about the other errors? How to resolve them?

Comment: If you already tried, are you still getting the Offline Mode error?  What happens if you try to create a new class that is not a batch?

Comment: it still throws error https://imgur.com/VCkEC6S